# How to prove that regular language is decidable

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language, turing-machines

I understand that i am trying to show that:
|  D is a DFA that accepts w

TM=with input

Stimulate D on w:

1) TM accepts if stimulation ends with accept state of the DFA D

2) TM rejects if stimulation ends with reject state (w was consumed and its not final state)

Is that enough? i am always having trouble writing down the actual proof although i understand the logic.

Comment: what do all your abbreviations mean?

Comment: Tm = turing machine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's enough. We know that the problem is decideable because a DFA always quits after $n$ steps on an input of size $n$, so the simulation is guaranteed to halt.